# Saving spliced arrays as separate variables using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, fetch

I currently have a function that takes in a JSON document and gives back all 3000 Item IDs. I am using the IDs in fetch loop to return information on each item ID from a API request. All is well, but because there is a 200 request limit / hour, I want to splice the array into separate arrays of 200 which would allow me to make separate calls on each array of IDs each hour. The idea is to queue up each request at different hours to keep in line with the limits, and then once the data is returned, I push the info to a corresponding array or JSON object which I will use later in my app.

Currently I am able to splice the array into the IDs that I want, but I am lost as to how to use the loop to give each array a specific variable/name that I can access. Currently I get get a list of arrays with numbers, but I want to give each array `let array1 = [1,...200]` , `let array2 = [201,...200]`, and so on.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```js
const ItemIDs = [];
function fetchItemIDs() {
  fetch("./db.json")
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(item) {
      for (i in item) {
        ItemIDs.push(item[i].id);
      }
      console.log(ItemIDs);
      var e = ItemIDs;
      while (e.length) {
        console.log(e.splice(0, 200));
      }
    });
}
fetchItemIDs();
```

I wont provide the JSOn file, but in short my output is simple an array of 3000 items, and then another output which shows the separate spliced arrays.

Thank you for the help / advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your 'db' calls should return results of X size you can repeat but if you have to use json from a file you could implement some kind of basic pagination for example:

```js
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

var batch_size = 3;
var offset = 0;
var current_batch = [];
var loop_count = 0;

var my_cool_batches = [];
var my_cool_batches_with_names = {};
do{
    var current_batch = array.splice(offset, batch_size);
    if(current_batch.length>0){
        console.log(current_batch); // [ "a", "b", "c" ] then [ "d", "e", "f" ] etc
        // do something
        my_cool_batches.push(current_batch);
        my_cool_batches_with_names[ 'array_' + String(loop_count) ] = current_batch;
    }
}while(current_batch.length>0)

console.log('all done');
```

Comment: I think I understand, and but I do not understand how to save each newly spliced array to a new dynamically created variable in the loop.

Basically, I am trying to splice an array by 200s, and then save each array of 200 numbers to an unique array I can call later like "array1" and "array2", and I want those variables to be created until the splicing is finished.

Comment: Easy done. Just assign them to an object or array for later access. See edit for example. You could then access like `my_cool_batches_with_names['array_2']` and get the 3rd 'batch' array

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `slice` instead?

```js
e1 = e.slice(0, 200)
e2 = e.slice(201)
```

Answer (score 0):

You neem to write a function which loops over an empty array and populates every index with a new array that contains a chunk of the array that you try to divide.

Then you can select each chunk from the newly created array by selecting the index.

```js
const arrayChunks = (array, size) => Array(Math.ceil(array.length / size)).fill()
  .map((entry, index) => index * size)
  .map(begin => array.slice(begin, begin + size));

const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const chunks = arrayChunks(values, 4);

const chunk = chunks[1];

console.log('Created chunks:', chunks);
console.log('A single chunk:', chunk);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you asked how to pick out sub-arrays of items and access them,

You can make your `ItemIDs` an array of array.
Now, when you iterate over the items in your

```
for (let i = 0; i <= item.length; i+= GROUP_SIZE ) {
     ItemIDs.push(item.slice(i, i + GROUP_SIZE));
}
```

You can keep track of the current group by assigning the index to some variable

```
let currentGroup = 0; // track the current group
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (currentGroup < ItemIds.length) {
      // you can then simply get the subgroup from index and iterate over it
      ItemIds[currentGroup].forEach(fetchSomething);  
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, INTERVAL);
```

But why, group elements, you can simply do

```
const GROUP_SIZE = 200;
function fetchItemIDs() {
fetch("./db.json")
  .then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json();
  })
  .then(function(item) {

     // start fetching
     let currentGroup = 0;
     const interval = setInterval(() => {
       if (currentGroup >= item.length) {
         clearInterval(interval);
       } else {
         for (let i = currentGroup; i < GROUP_SIZE; i++) {
           fetchSomething(i);
         }
       }

      }, INTERVAL);
    });
}
```

```js
const ItemIDs = [];
const GROUP_SIZE = 200;
function fetchItemIDs() {
  fetch("./db.json")
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(item) {
     
      for (let i = 0; i <= item.length; i+= GROUP_SIZE ) {
         ItemIDs.push(item.slice(i, i + GROUP_SIZE));
       }

       // start fetching
       let currentGroup = 0;
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (currentGroup < ItemIds.length) {
          ItemIds[currentGroup].forEach(fetchSomething);
        } else {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, INTERVAL);
    });
}
fetchItemIDs();
```